# OpenGL GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH 2D Antialiasing creating tris out of quads

Tags: c++, c, opengl, rotation, antialiasing

UPDATE:

I have located it to when I install NVIDIA Control Panel, if I uninstall it it works properly.

When you rotate a quad in OpenGL the edges become jagged.

If I call glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH) the edges become smooth, but OpenGL then draws a white diagonal line through all my images as if it's creating trisout of my quads.

This is how it looks:
[image: GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH]

Is there a way to disable that line, or can I get antialiasing in another easy way?
I tried GL_MULTISAMPLE but nothing happened.

In my code I have also:

```
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

glLoadIdentity();

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);

glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: It looks like the vertices on the two triangles just don't match up, creating the thin line. Instead of drawing a quad, try drawing a triangle fan. IMO, this line should go away because OpenGL now know which vertices are shared (and exactly equal).

Comment: Hmm okay, I understand the not matching up part. But I don't understand how I would draw two triangles holding half the image each and then rotating/scaling those individually.

at the moment I draw the texture onto a regular quad:

I'm pretty new to OpenGL and I haven't worked with triangles at all since I only work with 2D and images. So please point me in the direction of how draw a triangle fan.

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: Have you tested this on more than one computer with different graphics cards and/or tested with different drivers? It looks to me like it could be a driver bug.

Comment: It looks like your blend function is the issue. Have you tried other options from http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml ? Specifically, something like `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE,GL_ONE)` ?

Comment: @Jerry Coffin, Good call, I tested it on my laptop and the white lines were gone.
I've downloaded 3 different drivers for my desktop, 285.62, 295.51 and 295.53 but there's no difference. I use 460SLI and tried disabling one at a time but it still doesn't work.

Do you have any suggestion of what I could try to fix this?
Thanks,

Comment: @Orujimaru: If updating drivers does no good, about all you can do is complain to the vendor, and see if they will fix it or suggest a workaround. Those sound like nVidia version numbers, and I've had pretty good response from them in the past (but obviously can't guarantee anything). Some depends though -- they seem to put a lot more effort into their Windows drivers than Linux drivers.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Sorry, yes those are nvidia drivers for windows. 285 is the latest stable build and the 295 ones are more recent beta builds.

I'll contact Nvidia. Thanks a lot for your help!

//Markus

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'll write this up as an answer, let me know if it works after trying it out.

GL_TRIANGLE_FAN: If the application specifies a sequence of vertices v, OpenGL renders a triangle using v 0, v 1, and v 2; another triangle using v 0, v 2, and v 3; another triangle using v 0, v 3, and v 4; and so on. If the application specifies n vertices, OpenGL renders n–2 connected triangles.

So to draw a unit quad centered around the origin,

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);

glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
glVertex3f(-halfWidth, -halfHeight, 0f);

glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f);
glVertex3f(-halfWidth, halfHeight, 0f);

glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f);
glVertex3f(halfWidth, halfHeight, 0f);

glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f);
glVertex3f(halfWidth, -halfHeight, 0f);

glEnd();
```

Now you can put the same transformations around this that you used around your quad! Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, but this gives the exact same output as drawing a quad.
Thanks for the effort though.

//Markus

Comment: At this point I begin to suspect the driver and/or GPU as @jerrycoffin says above. Try it on some other GPU/driver.

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure that's it. Which is really strange.
I have never had any trouble with mu GPU's at all since I bought them 18 month ago. I tried a few different drivers, but that didn't help. I tried disabling one GPU at a time but that didn't help either. I have no idea how to troubleshoot the GPU itself. I can live with it if it's just my computer, but since I'm hoping to release the game I'm working on it's not acceptable if this occurs frequently =/